# Access server hosted on 127.0.0.1 within Guest OS from the Host OS in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, port-forwarding, netsh

I have a ColdFusion server that launches on 127.0.0.1:WXYZ within a virtual machine on VirtualBox. I need to be able to access the server from my Host OS. I have tried using a Bridged adapter as well as NAT with Port Forwarding, however, I have not managed.

I have also tried using normal NAT with port forwarding, whilst also using `netsh interface portproxy` to relay requests to attempt to expose the guest's internal 127.0.0.1.

Both the guest and the hosts are Windows 10. Changing the address that the server binds to is **not** an option in this scenario. I am not certain that I have attempted all the steps that I have mentioned in the ideal way, thus if you have any suggestions about anything that I have tried, or about anything I *could* try, please let me know.

Comment: By design, `localhost` is not reachable from outside the host. Is using additional tools (namely _socat_) acceptable?

Comment: Yes. I used netsh to try to replicate socat functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this myself in 3 steps. I'm going to post the answer in case this happens to anyone else. For this example, I have connected the Host OS' `localhost:3000` to the server that is running on `localhost:62094` on my Guest OS.

## Step 0 - THE MOST IMPORTANT STEP

Make sure that your Guest OS has File Sharing or Network Discovery turned on. This is why I was not able to access the Guest OS when @Peregrino69 mentioned it in the comments of another answer. Enabling this setting allowed me to ping the IP of the Guest OS *(not the localhost however, that required the remainder of the steps I took in this answer)*.

## 1. Find the Guest OS IP

This was done by running `ipconfig` and reading the `IPv4 Address`  field. In my case it was the default value of `10.0.2.15`.

## 2. Port Forward from the VirtualBox settings.

The second step is to port forward calls from the host's `localhost` to the guest by connecting `127.0.0.1:3000` to `10.0.2.15:3000` in the VM's network settings. This will relay calls made to `localhost:3000` in the Host OS to `10.0.2.15:3000` in the Guest OS. Screenshot of settings:

[image: Port forwarding]

## 3. Relay Calls to 10.0.2.15 to Guest's localhost

This was done by using the `netsh` command. The following exact command was used:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=10.0.2.15 listenport=3000 connectaddress=127.0.0.1 connectport=62094
```

This will relay calls made to `10.0.2.15:3000` to `localhost:62094` within the Guest OS.

## Result

This results in accessing `localhost:3000` from the Host OS incurring a response from `10.0.2.15:60294` in the Guest OS, where my server is hosted. I have attached a diagram of my final network setup, in case the steps were not clear enough:

[image: Network setup]

Answer (score 0):

The question suggests that you're trying to access the guest from the host using IP address 127.0.0.1. This cannot work, 127-addresses refer only to localhost. I.e. from the point of both computer systems, host and guest, 127.0.0.1 = "myself".

You need to use the actual interface IPs. For example I have a VB VM running with a bridged adapter. My Wi-Fi provides it IP address 192.168.43.177. My host connects to the same Wi-Fi, with IP address 192.168.43.28. If I want to access Webmin:s interface from within the VM, I can open the browser to https://127.0.0.1:10000, but if I want to access it from the host I have to open it to 192.168.43.177:10000.

This works the same way whether the interface is bridged or NATted.

Comment: To make it clear, I don't require the IP address to be 127.0.0.1 when trying to connect from the Host OS. I just want to be able to access the 127.0.0.1 that is hosted in the guest...FROM the Host.

Comment: You simply use the actual IP address of the guest OS. In my example for my VM both `127.0.0.1` and `192.168.43.177` mean "myself". You'll find the guest's accessible IP address with command `ipconfig` if it's Windows; or `ifconfig` or `ip addr` on Linux. You need to run the command on the guest OS.

Comment: [When in NAT mode] Using `ipconfig`, I am told that my Guest OS has IP `10.0.2.15`. The port that the server is running on is `62094`, thus I am pinging `10.0.2.15:62094` from my host OS. This results in an error. Pinging the same address from my Guest OS also does not work. The only way I have been able to access this server is by accessing `127.0.0.1:62094` from the Guest OS.

Comment: You can't ping a port, that's not how ping works; only the IP address. Trying to ping a port always returns an error. You can `ping 10.0.2.15` and if it responds, try `telnet 10.0.2.15 62094`. If the port's working you will get `Connected to 10.0.2.15` and possibly escape character. You can then break the connection with `Ctrl`+`C` and try to access the server with `10.0.2.15:62094`.

Comment: `curl`, I meant to say `curl` not `ping`.

Comment: Troubleshooting is baby steps :-D First you need to establish the IP address is reachable in the first place, that's what `ping` is for. Only when you know that you can begin assessing why the port isn't.

Comment: [In Bridged Network Mode] IPConfig reports that my Guest Machine has IP `172.16.29.8`. When attempting to `curl` `172.16.29.8:62094` from the guest machine, it fails. Thus I have set up a relay using netsh to port forward requests from `172.16....` to `127.0.0.1:62094`. This lets me access the server from `172.16.29.8:62094`. However, when I access `172.16.29.8:62094` from my Host machine, it does not work. Am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't I be able to access this directly since it is in bridged mode ?

Comment: The guest is always directly accessible, whether in NAT or bridged mode, if there's no firewall or other security measure preventing the communication. Again, baby steps, start with ping and telnet; doing anything else like port forwarding before that just complicates things.

Comment: I have managed to solve the entire issue. Re: Your comment that the guest is always accessible, see [STEP - 0] in my answer to my own question. Windows Guest OSs need to have file sharing or network discovery turned on before you can access the guest OS, otherwise, you will not be able to access them from either Bridge or NAT mode. (I am not 100% sure of this, but this is what I have found to be true throughout my entire day spent debugging this issue).

Comment: Great that you got the issue resolved! :-) You might have to wait for a couple of days, but please do accept your own answer when you can. That'll signal to others who might be facing similar issues later down the line that here's a possible solution to try.